# Spring Batch Admin, could not replace placeholder 'batch.business.schema.script'

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

Trying to add Spring Batch Admin to an existing Spring Batch project.

I have already updated web.xml with spring-batch-admin-resources and spring-batch-admin-manager

My setup:

Under **src/main/resources/**

I have added 2 properties files.  1 is batch-default-properties which is an empty file, and the other is batch-sqlserver.properties whith contents below:

```
batch.jdbc.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver    batch.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.xxx:1433;DatabaseName=SpringBatch
batch.jdbc.user=user
batch.jdbc.password=password
batch.jdbc.testWhileIdle=false
batch.jdbc.validationQuery=
batch.drop.script=/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-sqlserver.sql
batch.schema.script=/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-sqlserver.sql
batch.database.incrementer.class=org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.SqlServerMaxValueIncrementer
batch.lob.handler.class=org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.DefaultLobHandler
batch.business.schema.script=business-schema-sqlserver.sql
batch.database.incrementer.parent=columnIncrementerParent
batch.grid.size=2
batch.jdbc.pool.size=6
batch.verify.cursor.position=true
batch.isolationlevel=ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE
batch.table.prefix=BATCH_
batch.data.source.init=false
```

under **webapp/META-INF/spring/batch/override/**, I have added data-source-context.xml with contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

       <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
              <property name="jndiName">
                     <value>java:jboss/datasources/springBatchDB</value>
              </property>
       </bean>
</beans>
```

This is run within JBoss EAP 6.3.  Everytime I start the server, it gives this exception:

```
11:58:36,116 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 112) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0' defined in null: Could not resolve placeholder 'batch.business.schema.script' in string value "${batch.business.schema.script}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'batch.business.schema.script' in string value "${batch.business.schema.script}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:211) [spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:223) [spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:86) [spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265) [spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:162) [spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) [spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462) [spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663) [spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629) [spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677) [spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548) [spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489) [spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1100) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3591) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3798) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:59) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:94) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'batch.business.schema.script' in string value "${batch.business.schema.script}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174) [spring-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) [spring-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:259) [spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:282) [spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:204) [spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitIndexedArgumentValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:150) [spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:84) [spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:169) [spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:141) [spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:82) [spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:169) [spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitList(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:228) [spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:192) [spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:141) [spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:82) [spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:169) [spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:141) [spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:82) [spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:208) [spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 26 more
```

I see that batch.business.schema.script is coming from:

`spring-batch-admin-manager/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/batch/bootstrap/manager/data-source-context.xml`,

in there there is also "${batch.schema.script}" which is loaded from my batch-sqlserver.properties but not the batch.business.schema.script.

Does anyone know why or have any suggestions??
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem as well. I didn't have a separate override `data-source-context.xml`, but I solved it by launching the server (tomcat in my case) with a JVM option called ENVIRONMENT:

`-DENVIRONMENT=postgresql`.

In your case it would be:

`-DENVIRONMENT=sqlserver`

My guess is that the spring batch app uses spring profiles to choose which database types to use and needs the initial flag to seed things.

For reference, here's the post from David Syer on this:

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/105054-spring-batch-admin-configuration-for-pointing-the-database?p=562140#post562140

For the override context approach he says:

> Or you can go with the override XML, as long as you put it in the
>   right location - from the user guide "add your own versions of the
>   same bean definitions to a Spring XML config file in
>   META-INF/spring/batch/override" **(that's in the classpath, not the war
>   file META-INF)**. In that case just override the bean named
>   "dataSource".

So you have the file in the wrong place. You need to move it to a directory on your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try override the placeholderProperties including your own properties.

Let suppose you place your properties on application.properties, then it would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!--  Use this to set additional properties on beans at run time -->
    <bean id="placeholderProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/org/springframework/batch/admin/bootstrap/batch.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:batch-default.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:batch-${ENVIRONMENT:hsql}.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```